# foursquare api hereNow list checked in people without being checked in yourself

Tags: php, api, foursquare

I'm trying to get the list of users that are checked in a venue.
using following url (php):

```
 $url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/5576e64f498e907e749435d4/herenow?client_id=' . $fsClientId 
    . '&oauth_token=' . $_SESSION['foursquareToken']->access_token . '&v=20130815';
```

If i'm checked in to the same venue I get a list of people who are checked in to the venue. If i'm not checked in there's an empty "items" object(I've json_decoded it to an object):

> `stdClass Object ( [meta] => stdClass Object ( [code] => 200 ) [notifications] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [type] => notificationTray [item] => stdClass Object ( [unreadCount] => 0 ) ) ) [response] => stdClass Object ( [hereNow] => stdClass Object ( [count] => 1 [items] => Array ( ) ) ) )`

Is it possible to list people checked in to a venue without being checked in to it yourself?
I've read somewhere you have to be venue-owner for this being able to work. Is that correct?
How does one become venue-owner in that case?

Or is it truely not possible at all?

Thanks in advance.

MackDoms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to list people checked in to a venue without being checked in to it yourself?

Yes, it is possible. You do not need to check in there. However, a list that you can see, the only friends of your friends or friends.

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/herenow

> Returns a list of friends and friends-of-friends at the venue for authenticated requests. If the acting user is currently checked in to the venue, then a list of other users is also returned.